# Accessing query string variables sent as POST in HttpActionContext

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm trying to access a query string parameter that was sent using the POST method (WebClient) to the Web API in ASP.NET MVC 5 (in an overridden AuthorizationFilterAttribute).

For Get, I've used the following trick:

`var param= actionContext.Request.GetQueryNameValuePairs().SingleOrDefault(x => x.Key.Equals("param")).Value;`

However, once I use POST, this does work and the variable *paran* is set to null. I think that's because the query string method only applies to the url, not the body. Is there any way to get the query string (using one method preferably) for both GET and POST requests?

**EDIT: WebClient Code**

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
        NameValueCollection reqparm = new NameValueCollection();

        reqparm.Add("param", param);

        byte[] responsebytes = client.UploadValues("https://localhost:44300/api/method/", "POST", reqparm);
        string responsebody = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(responsebytes);

        return Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(responsebody);

    }
}
```

Comment: You seem to come from a PHP background. Contrary to what that language makes you believe (`$_GET`), the verb used to request the page is not at all associated with the query string. It is just that: the part after the `?` in the request-URI. Show the WebClient code you use to send the POST request; obivously you're not setting the query string parameters properly there.

Comment: @CodeCaster, I think it's simply the Web API that makes all the trouble. In any other case, either Request["name"] (just like in PHP :) ) or specifying the parameter in the method signature would do (both for GET and POST). For Web API, it seems to be more complex.

Comment: No, it's not. `actionContext.Request.GetQueryNameValuePairs()` will give you the parameters from the query string, regardless of with what verb the current action method was requested. Show your WebClient code.

Comment: @CodeCaster, Ok, I've now added WebClient code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the code you show, you upload the `param=value` in the request body using the `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` content-type.

If you also want to utilize the query string, you need to set it separately using the [`WebClient.QueryString` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.querystring(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
// Query string parameters
NameValueCollection queryStringParameters = new NameValueCollection();
queryStringParameters.Add("someOtherParam", "foo");
client.QueryString = queryStringParameters;

// Request body parameters
NameValueCollection requestParameters = new NameValueCollection();
requestParameters.Add("param", param);

client.UploadValues(uri, method, requestParameters);
```

This will make the request go to `uri?someOtherParam=foo`, enabling you to read the query string parameters serverside through `actionContext.Request.GetQueryNameValuePairs()`.

Comment: Is there any way to read the request body parameters using methods available in Web API (on the server side)?

Comment: @Artem `await Request.Content.ReadAsFormDataAsync()`, which will give you yet another `NameValueCollection`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! :) +1